# Google plus API and Gmail API integration in android app

Tags: android

In android I need to create an app where user can login through google account and can access its basic profile information and its inbox mails also. How do I integrate google plus API and gmail API together. 
Also please let me know how to integrate gmail API to access mails.

Comment: see this link it's easy to understand for google plus api and integration http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: I'm using the same link for google plus API integration. But need to access mails also.

Comment: it is not clear whether you're looking for a library to access gmail or you could not find  [gmail api documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/). Nonetheless, google has great [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) for using the gmail api on android.

Comment: Actually I need to get the inbox's primary messages. Can you please let me know how to get that.

Comment: by using gmail api we can get inbox messages and we can search also and we can get any sent Messages and all we can get just go through gmail api, First time you may not understand what is what. After that you can know how to do, you may get Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Google+ sign-in lets users sign in to your Android app with their existing Google account and get their profile information like name, email, profile pic and other details. By integrating google plus login in your apps, you can get all the user details in one shot. Not only login, you can do other things like posting to their g+ account, getting list of circles, friends list and lot more. The major advantage of integrating G+ login is, you can drive more users to your app by providing quicker & easiest way of registration process.

visit

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: But I need to access mails also. For that I need to integrate gmail API.